# How to set bottom position of a link inside header

Tags: html, css, css-position

how can I set position of my link elements to bottom of header?

```css
header {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 500px;
  background-color: grey;
  border-bottom: solid blue 6px;
}

a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 125px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid blue 2px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</header>
```

I tried to set `bottom: 0;` but with no result. I have also tried with margin-top and padding-top but result is different height of header. If I set margin or padding by 200px, I get header higher for 200px.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just edit css of header to this:

```css
header{
       height: 200px;
       width: 100%;
       padding-left: 500px;
       background-color: grey;
       border-bottom: solid blue 6px;
    
       display: flex;
       flex-direction: row;
       justify-content: center;
       align-items: flex-end;
    }

a {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 125px;
 height: 50px;
 border: solid blue 2px;
 padding-left: 2px;
 border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 50px;
 color: white;
 background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</header>
```

Comment: you should add comments and explain what you did or at least link to some referenze

Comment: Yes @TommySchmidt !

I read carefully the question of question owner. And I did some modify to the code and it works.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to set a `position` for your `header`, in this case it will be `relative`. 
Second you will have to use a container to keep your links from falling apart. I will call it `.menuHolder` and this will have all the menu links in side itself.

Then in order to place them at the bottom of header, you need to set an `absolute` position on your link container. in this case `.menuHolder` and again; this is because we don't want the links to freely seperate from eachother, we want them to stay in place.

```css
header {
 height: 200px;
 width: 100%;
 padding-left: 500px;
 background-color: grey;
 border-bottom: solid blue 6px;
 position: relative;   /* RELATIVE POSITION ON HEADER TO KEEP ANYYTHING WITH ABSOLUTE POS INSIDE IT */
}

a {
 display: block;
 float: left;
 width: 125px;
 height: 50px;
 border: solid blue 2px;
 padding-left: 2px;
 border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 50px;
 color: white;
 background-color: black;
}

/* A CONTAINER FOR LINKS WHICH WILL KEEP LINK FROM COLLAPSING INTO EACHOTHER*/
.menuHolder {
 position: absolute; /* TO BE ABLE TO FREELY PLACE IT */
 bottom: 0;/* MAKE IT STICK TO BOTTOM */
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<header>
 <div class="menuHolder">
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
 </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you add position:relative to the header and position:absolute to the link attributes, then the bottom:0 will work as you expect.

```css
header {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
  padding-left: 500px;
  background-color: grey;
  border-bottom: solid blue 6px;
  position:relative;
}

a {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 125px;
  height: 50px;
  border: solid blue 2px;
  padding-left: 2px;
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</header>
```

Comment: This is not working like this, you can see in code snippet. I set my links inside div which has absolute position and bottom 0 and it works now.

Comment: ... and cause them to collapse into eachother.

Comment: The question appears to have changed after I suggested my answer. My code snippet above is duplicated from what I read initially, just adding the position attributes. Which works fine. So getting a downvote is ... just rude?